# Why doesn't render animation work?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I made a rather simple animation using video sequence editor (mostly blinking between two images), but for some reason I cannot render it. When I clicked render animation, all I see in the render result window is the blank "image" and nothing happens. I made the animation in blender 2.8 and I though maybe there is a problem in blender 2.8, but it didn't work (the same file) in blender 2.79 either. This was the second try of the same animation, first rendered fine, but crashed so I had to start over. This is what I get: [image]
I can render image and get the first image of the video.

Comment: In the Render Tab under Post Processing have you got Sequencer checked?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the title and ID for a youtube video that explains step by step how to render an animation.  He is excellent at explaining things and would do it better than I.  Hope it helps.

Title:  How to Render Animations in Blender

ID: dd5RT8rEPqU

Here's the link:  [RenderingVideo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dd5RT8rEPqU)

Comment: why can't you just paste the url?

Comment: sure, I'll do that